# Can't call a method with another method, what am I missing?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Extremely basic objective-c question here. I want to call a method from within another method and send a variable from the first method to the second method, but I'm not sure how to handle this with @implementation, etc.

Here is what I want:

```
-(int) isItFav:(int) favNum
{
 // some code   
}

- (IBAction)myBar:(UISegmentedControl *)sender
{
 // some code
 int x = 10;
 [isItFav x];
}
```

This causes as error, as isItFav is an undeclared identifier. Can someone please tell me how to fix this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both `myBar:` and `isItFav:` are in same class:

```
int returnedValue = [self isItFav:x];
```

If in different class, then

```
int returnedValue = [objectOfClassWhichContainsIsItFavMethod isItFav:x];
```

*This is Objective-C. Please see tutorials and manuals.*

Comment: Wonderful, thanks for helping me with my beginner's question. I'll accept after the time limit!

Answer (score 0):

[receiverOfCall method:param];

This case:
int result = [self isItFav:x];

Answer (score 0):

Message Call Format is

```
[sender message:params]
```